# Use of memory management functions in cross platform library

Tags: c, memory-management, cross-platform

I'm creating a cross platform library using C.  I have a piece of code like the following, in which I'm using the libc memory management functions directly:

```
myObject* myObjectCreate(void)
{
    ...
    myObject *pObject = (myObject*)malloc(sizeof(*pObject));
    ...
}

void myObjectDestroy(myObject *pObject)
{
    ...
    free(pObject);
    ...
}
```

I understand these memory management functions are not always available, especially on embedded systems based on low-end microcontrollers.  Unfortunately my library needs to be compilable on these systems.

To work around this problem, I suppose I'd have to make these functions customisable by my library client.

So, what are the recommended ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function pointers.

Define the following pointers in the library:

```
void* (*CustomMalloc)(size_t) = NULL;
void (*CustomFree)(void*) = NULL;
```

And prior to using of the library functions initialize these pointers to point to custom implementations of `malloc()` and `free()`. Or initialize them to point to the real `malloc()` and `free()`.

Inside of the library replace `malloc(size)` with `CustomMalloc(size)` and `free(pointer)` with `CustomFree(pointer)`.

Comment: Still though - there needs to be a mechanism by which the code knows whether to point at malloc() or a dummy malloc().  The use of function pointers doesn't address that.

Comment: @BlankXavier I'm not sure I'm seeing a problem here. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches.

I use #if, combined with compiler provided defines, to have per platform behaviour.

Should a given functionality (such as malloc) be found, #define MYLIB_MALLOC can be defined.

Then, later, you can check for #ifdef MYLIB_MALLOC and if not present, provide a dummy malloc function, which will allow your code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional compile, i.e. define some macro's like `LIBC_AVAIL`, `LIBC_NOT_AVAIL` and include different code when compiling.